# Synonize [hangouts] with [google-hangouts]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

[hangouts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hangouts) has 12 questions, all referring to Google Hangouts.  We also have a [google-hangouts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts) tag with 38 questions.  Suggest synonomizing [hangouts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hangouts) with [google-hangouts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-hangouts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

> hangouts will be removed from 12 questions
> google-hangouts will be added to 11 questions
>
> A tag synonym mapping hangouts → google-hangouts will be created.